# Using Zend tableGateway to INSERT on one table and UPDATE another

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2, tablegateway

Supose you have a module called orders, which when it adds, It should update a value on another module (table of another module), and orders does include the id of the other module it its table. I plan on doing this with Zend's TableGateway, But I have no idea how would I alter other table.

Comment: Please provide some background in order for us to help. What have you tried? Do you have any code examples?

Comment: not really I haven't got my mind around how to do it all i could show you is how i'm relating fields, which is by a mapper between  model tables

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can trigger an event after order insert.
In your second module create an listener for your order insert event.